# Sync multiple Outlook calendars with Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar, synchronization, outlook

Is there any way to sync multiple Outlook calendars with Google Calendar? Google Calendar sync can just sync one calendar.

Answer (score 2):

I found a really good way to do this is to set up an [iCloud account in outlook](http://www.apple.com/icloud/setup/pc.html).  I did this to get outlook to sync with my IPod Touch, so I had it in place anyway.  Then you can use [Smoothsync for iCloud calendar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.dmfs.caldav.icloud&hl=en)

Note that for Jelly Bean users: To prevent the removal of your accounts on reboot, first install the workaround app described in the information on the app.

The smoothsync for iCalendar app costs $2.76 and is totally worth it.  The "workaround" app is free.

There is a similar app for your contacts, SmoothSync for iCloud calendar that is $3.88.  Also totally worth it.  There is a similar workaround app for Jellybean.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add these calendars by using the CalDav protocol. This way you can have all your calendars bi-directional synced.

See also the [getting started guide](http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?answer=99358) from Google.

Though for Outlook you might need some third party software, like [Open Connector](http://openconnector.org/), to get things running.

*I don't have Outlook here to test this for you.*

Answer (score 1):

[gSyncit](http://www.fieldstonsoftware.com/software/gsync)

This is a commercial software (with a free limited trial). It is not perfect, has it's flaws. However, this is the only software I have found that syncs between Outlook (Calendar/Contact/Notes/Tasks) and Gmail.

You can also ask it to sync to multiple Google accounts.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

[Sync2](http://sync2.com) allows to sync selected Google calendars with your Outlook.
Check out this: http://sync2.com/google-calendar-sync-outlook.aspx